# Get the input value in React hooks and print it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I am trying to print the value of input on the screen, but it keeps updating every time I enter a new character.

```
/*Import*/
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Search.scss";
/*Component*/
const Search = () => {
  /*State*/
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  /*On Form Submit*/

  return (
    <>
      <div className="Search">
        <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()} className="Search__form">
          <input
            value={input}
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
            type="text"
            placeholder="&#xF002; Title, companies, expertise, or benefits"
            style={{ fontFamily: "Arial, FontAwesome" }}
          ></input>
          <button onclick={console.log(input)}>Search</button>
        </form>
        <h1>{input}</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

/*Exprting*/
export default Search;
```

I just want to print the whole value after I click the button

Comment: `onclick` is supposed to be a function, but you're passing `undefined` (because that's what `console.log()` returns). Pass a function instead, like `() => console.log(input)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `console.log(input)` on each rerender instead of only on click. Convert it to an arrow function and it should do what you want.

```
<button onClick={()=>console.log(input)}>Search</button>
```

EDIT: To answer your follow-up question: You need two separate state variables:

```
/*Import*/
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Search.scss";
/*Component*/
const Search = () => {
  /*State*/
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  // new state variable
  const [submittedInput, setSubmittedInput] = useState("");
  /*On Form Submit*/

  return (
    <>
      <div className="Search">
        <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()} className="Search__form">
          <input
            value={input}
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
            type="text"
            placeholder="&#xF002; Title, companies, expertise, or benefits"
            style={{ fontFamily: "Arial, FontAwesome" }}
          ></input>
          <button onClick={()=>setSubmittedInput(input)}>Search</button>
        </form>
        <h1>{submittedInput}</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: It also needs to be `onClick` in camel case.

Comment: Mate thanks very much, just one thing more, <h1>{input}</h1>, keep changing every time , how I print it once I click on the button ?

Comment: MATE, THANKS VERY MUCH!! Much appreciated, you solved my problem forever !!